# google chrome not submitting form (js errors?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

I can't get Google Chrome to submit my form.  It's getting pretty ridiculous.  It ends up focusing a random form field (but it's the same one every time) instead.

No issues with FF or IE...

Two of the errors Chrome gives me in developer tools are:

```
An invalid form control with name='state' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='unitName' is not focusable.
```

BUT, these aren't even the one field that chrome is deciding to focus on.  I'm at a loss, any one had any experience like this??

Comment: are you able to show us some code? what do your forms and JS look like?

Comment: Well, it's an enormous form I'll be honest...  but i have many similar forms to this,  and they have no problems.

Comment: Is there any structural difference between your working forms and this non-working form?

Comment: You probably have two form fields named `state` and `unitName`; can we see those?

Comment: Want to add that the correct answer to this is:  `maxlength caused issues. I removed them all, and no more woes.`  I'm sure this may be a common issue for those using jQuery to aid in populating fields w/ Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML, here's what a little Google'ing turned up:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45831
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45640
- [http://domoconnor.com/2010/08/05/browser-issue-an-invalid-form-control-with-name-*_*_-is-not-focusable/](http://domoconnor.com/2010/08/05/browser-issue-an-invalid-form-control-with-name-____-is-not-focusable/)

The root of the problem appears to be assigning a `maxlength` attribute to a form field that is automatically populated by the browser, with a value that is longer than the maxlength limit.

Comment: @Wesley Exactly! :) I removed it from my answer though, it seemed better suited to a comment

Comment: maxlength it was.  I removed them all, and no more woes!  Thanks man!!

Comment: thanks - for me it was a required field, hidden via the tagInput plugin

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem with an input field marked "required" that was made invisible via javascript. Chrome could not display "please fill out this field" so it said An invalid form control with name='description' is not focusable in the console.

Comment: Same here.  Found similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168645/invalid-form-control-only-in-google-chrome

Comment: Has anyone got code that can catch this error so we can handle it in Javascript? can't exactly wrap a try{} block around a form submission!

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, and for me, the fix was adding `type="button"` into my `<button>` tag.