# "Invalid form control" only in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

The code below works well in Safari but in Chrome and Firefox the form will not submit.  Chrome console logs the error `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable`.  Any ideas?

Note that whilst the controls below do not have names, they should have names at the time of submission, populated by the Javascript below.  The form DOES work in Safari.

```
<form method="POST" action="/add/bundle"> 
<p> 
    <input type="text" name="singular" placeholder="Singular Name" required> 
    <input type="text" name="plural" placeholder="Plural Name" required> 
</p> 
<h4>Asset Fields</h4> 
<div class="template-view" id="template_row" style="display:none"> 
    <input type="text" data-keyname="name" placeholder="Field Name" required> 
    <input type="text" data-keyname="hint" placeholder="Hint"> 
    <select data-keyname="fieldtype" required> 
        <option value="">Field Type...</option> 
        <option value="Email">Email</option> 
        <option value="Password">Password</option> 
        <option value="Text">Text</option> 
    </select>    
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="required" value="true"> Required
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="search" value="true"> Searchable
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="readonly" value="true"> ReadOnly
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="autocomplete" value="true"> AutoComplete
    <input type="radio" data-keyname="label" value="label" name="label"> Label
    <input type="radio" data-keyname="unique" value="unique" name="unique"> Unique
    <button class="add" type="button">+</button> 
    <button class="remove" type="button">-</button> 
</div> 

<div id="target_list"></div> 
    <p><input type="submit" name="form.submitted" value="Submit" autofocus></p> 
</form>

<script> 
function addDiv()
{
    var pCount = $('.template-view', '#target_list').length;
    var pClone = $('#template_row').clone();
    $('select, input, textarea', pClone).each(function(idx, el){
        $el = $(this);
        if ((el).type == 'radio'){
            $el.attr('value', pCount + '_' + $el.data('keyname'));
        }
        else {
            $el.attr('name', pCount + '_' + $el.data('keyname'));
        };
    });
    $('#target_list').append(pClone);
    pClone.show();
}

function removeDiv(elem){
    var pCount = $('.template-view', '#target_list').length;
    if (pCount != 1)
    {
        $(elem).closest('.template-view').remove();
    }
};

$('.add').live('click', function(){
    addDiv();
});

$('.remove').live('click', function(){
    removeDiv(this);
});

$(document).ready(addDiv);

</script>
```

Comment: Only [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) controls will be sent. To be successful, a control **must** have a name. There are other requirements too (see link).

Comment: The radio buttons have names.  Everything else gets a name via the JavaScript.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Chrome wants to focus on a control that is required but still empty so that it can pop up the message 'Please fill out this field'.  However, if the control is hidden at the point that Chrome wants to pop up the message, that is at the time of form submission, Chrome can't focus on the control because it is hidden, therefore the form won't submit.

So, to get around the problem, when a control is hidden by javascript, we also must remove the 'required' attribute from that control.

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Makes sense though I guess, the browser can't possibly guess how it wants your interface to deal with the validation error messages if the field is hidden (maybe a tabbed form...).

Comment: Thanks, this works. It's a shame Chrome does this though, it should just skip the field.

Comment: I had this issue in Chrome for textarea when text length in textarea was more than 4100 letters, no hidden required fields. When text length is < 4000 everything works, otherwise in the console I can see that message and can't submit form

Comment: If the field is not required when it is hidden, wouldn't it make even more sense to disable it instead? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22753533/421243)

Comment: What if this error still occurs on Chrome but the field is not empty? Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I DON'T HAVE `required` fields. Sorry to scream, but everyone everywhere talks about this type of fields, and my problem persist.

Comment: this resolved the problem for me =>                                                          
$(function() { 
         $('#your_form_name input').removeAttr('required');
 });

Comment: That's all well and nice, but it would be much more helpful of Chrome to also tell me the invalid field. Now I can search my nested dynamic forms for all kinds of validation issues all on my own.  Going to write a bug report there now. Although it won't help me now.

Answer (score 13):

It will show that message if you have code like this:

```
<form>
  <div style="display: none;">
    <input name="test" type="text" required/>
  </div>

  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

solution to this problem will depend on how the site should work

for example if you don't want the form to submit unless this field is required you should disable the submit button

so the js code to show the div should enable the submit button as well

you can hide the button too (should be disabled and hidden because if it's hidden but not disabled the user can submit the form with others way like press `enter` in any other field but if the button is disabled this won't happen

if you want the form to submit if the div is hidden you should disable any required input inside it and enable the inputs while you are showing the div

if someone need the codes to do so you should tell me exactly what you need

Comment: Yes ..can you please tell solution for this?

Comment: @RexRex i edit the answer see if this help you or tell me what exactly do you need

Comment: @KaziMasumBillah i don't understand you can you write example in answer please

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about HTML5 validation (maybe you are validating in JS or on the server), you could try adding "novalidate" to the form or the input elements.

Comment: people should never do things like that he should make his js code work with html5 not just shut html5 because he can't deal with it

Comment: I don't agree. You just need a good reason to do things differently. There are still plenty of powerful validation libraries out there. HTML5 validation is easy, quick to set up. And above all it is good to follow standards. But that does not mean that it is "the best" solution. Never say never. It always depends. Although I do agree that you should "never" skip client validation completely. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

try to use proper tags for HTML5 controls
Like for Number(integers)

```
<input type='number' min='0' pattern ='[0-9]*' step='1'/>
```

for Decimals or float

```
 <input type='number' min='0' step='Any'/>
```

**step='Any'** Without this you cannot submit your form entering any decimal or float value like 3.5 or 4.6 in the above field.

Try fixing the pattern , type for HTML5 controls to fix this issue.

Comment: you solved my problem. But pay attention that `pattern` doesn't seem to be universally acceptable in `type="number"` field

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error, and determined it was actually on a field that was not hidden.

In this case, it was a `type="number"` field, that is required. When no value has ever been entered into this field, the error message is shown in the console, and the form is not submitted. Entering a value, and then removing it means that the validation error is shown as expected.

I believe this is a bug in Chrome: my workaround for now was to come up with an initial/default value.

Comment: Possible bug in Chrome. Also happened to me. +1

Answer (score 2):

I have to do something like this to fix the bug, since I have some `type="number"` with `min="0.00000001"`:

#### HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="0.00000001" step="0.00000001" name="price" value="[%price%]" />
```

#### JS:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
    //prevent chrome bug
    $("input:hidden").val(null);
});
```

If I don't set all hidden input field to `null` chrome will still try to validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the error:

> An invalid form control with name='telefono' is not focusable.

This was happening because I was not using the required field correctly, which enabled and disabled when clicking on a checkbok. The solution was to remove the `required` attribute  whenever the checkbok was not marked and mark it as required when the checkbox was marked.

```
var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono");  
telefono.removeAttribute("required");
```

Answer (score 1):

No validate will do the job.

```
<form action="whatever" method="post" novalidate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had class="hidden" on the input fields because I was using buttons instead of radio bullets - and changing the "active" state via JS..

I simply added an extra radio input field part of the same group where i wanted the msg to appear:

```
<input type="radio" id="thenorm" name="ppoption" value=""  required style="opacity:0"/>
```

the other 2 active bullets are invisible, this one isnt and this triggers the validation message and no console errors - bit of a hack but what isnt these days..

Answer (score 0):

this error get if add decimal format.
i just add

```
step="0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when I entered a number (999999) that was out of the range I'd set for the form.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="clipInMovieModel" id="clipInMovie" min="1" max="10000">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("...").attr("required"); and $("...").removeAttr("required");
```

didn't work for me until I putted all my jQuery code between that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //jQuery code goes here
});
```

Answer (score -7):

replace `required` by required="required"

Comment: Required is an HTML5 attribute and and "required" has the same meaning with required='required' because it has no other attributes available.