# Form Control Fault Workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, error-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to get around the:

> An invalid form control with name='dob_mm' is not focusable.

Error that comes in Chrome. Yes, we have a bunch of fields that are required, and yes, these fields are hidden. The form is broken out into tabs, which only one show at a time.

Is there some type of Jquery function that can show some type of popup saying "you must fill out the information in the other tabs"?

I look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168645/invalid-form-control-only-in-google-chrome) but didn't tell me much.

Comment: how can a hidden input be given property required? Validate it with script instead

Answer (score 11):

You should do your own validation but as a backup there *is* a workaround to prevent against these errors in Chrome.

The basic method is this:

- In the submit button click event detect which field failed the browser validation using the `:invalid` pseudo-class that Chrome adds to the field with the error.
- Find that field's parent container (eg the tab it's on) and make that container visible.

This will ensure that the user is directed to the tab with the error and Chrome's validation will not fail because the field will be focusable.

A very basic version is something like this:

```
$('#inputbutton').click(function(){
    //find the invalid field
    $('#myform').find(':invalid').first()
    //find it's parent tab and show it
    .parents('.tab-pane').show();
});
```

Comment: for firefox you should use find('input:invalid,select:invalid,textarea:invalid') because the first element which is invalid could be a fieldset

Comment: What if the invalid fields are in different tabs?

Comment: @TurdalievNursultan it only picks the *first* invalid control.