# An invalid form control is not focusable

Tags: css

I have custom checkboxes (show images for states checked and unchecked). but when i submit a form i get the following error `n invalid form control with name='X' is not focusable.`

I can understand the reason. but **How i can have a foucusable transparent checkbox?**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  outline: none !important;
  display: none;
}
```

- Browser: Chromium 25.0.1364.160
- Framwrok : Flat-UI

Comment: http://domoconnor.com/2010/08/05/browser-issue-an-invalid-form-control-with-name-____-is-not-focusable/

Comment: What browser? What framework? Getting the error where exactly?

Comment: @Oded look the update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168645/invalid-form-control-only-in-google-chrome

Comment: @PeterVR i dont want remove the `required` attr

Comment: Do your own validation with javascript (on submit of the form) and display an error message on your 'custom' checkbox if the field is not checked...

Comment: i'm using the built-it HTML5 validation

Comment: Still persists in 28..

Comment: maybe this post helps you "Easy CSS3 Checkboxes and Radio Buttons" http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: @dsuess the problem is when you uses the property `display: none` that tutorial make uses that