# How can I make reCAPTCHA a required field?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I'm using Google reCAPTCHA and have been able to add the CAPTCHA component to my page inside a form. But when I submit the form there's no validation taking place to check if the CAPTCHA has been solved.

How do I validate that the CAPTCHA component has been solved when submitting my form? Or, in other words, how do I make my CAPTCHA component required?

Comment: Sorry gpullen but i want to do reCAPTCHA as required field in the form.

Comment: Try this link - [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Posting your code along with a link to the relevant Google product page would be far more useful to everyone than posting an animated gif. Thanks.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

if you want to use the native html5 popups, than here is the solution

JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const $recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response');
  if ($recaptcha) {
    $recaptcha.setAttribute('required', 'required');
  }
})
```

CSS:

```
#g-recaptcha-response {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -78px 0 0 0 !important;
  width: 302px !important;
  height: 76px !important;
  z-index: -999999;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but get an error "An invalid form control with name='g-recaptcha-response' is not focusable."

Comment: @timkado Do you have a Codepen for me?

Comment: @timkado works like expected: https://codepen.io/internetztube/pen/aaoLqM

Comment: Hi Fred - this is very strange. I copied your code and I am still getting the same error: An invalid form control with name='g-recaptcha-response' is not focusable.

Comment: @timkado What browser on what os do you use?

Comment: I am on Win8, latest version Chrome

Comment: This answer worked for me on Chrome, FF, Edge and Opera. Why isn't it working on IE 11? Any specific reason? The required attribute isn't being added to the #g-recaptcha-response id. Why?

Comment: @Fernando Do you have a Codepen for me?

Comment: It worked well for me. There happened the same error @timkado met but was removed after adding the given CSS style. It's because the target Textarea has "display: none;" by default. Thanks, @Fred!

Comment: So close, but if the captcha expires, this doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem as yours and solved it this way:

First declare a variable that stores `1` or `0` depending or whether the user filled the capcha correctly.

```
var allowSubmit = false;
```

Then you need a function which gets executed when the user fills the reCapcha correctly:

```
function capcha_filled () {
    allowSubmit = true;
}
```

... and a function that gets executed when the reCapcha session expires:

```
function capcha_expired () {
    allowSubmit = false;
}
```

To tell reCapcha about your functions (callbacks), set those `data-`attributes in your html:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"
   data-callback="capcha_filled"
   data-expired-callback="capcha_expired"
   data-sitekey="your site key"></div>
```

Or if you use explicit load:

```
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('your_div_id', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
      'callback': capcha_filled,
      'expired-callback': capcha_expired,
    });
  };
```

You need also a callback for the form submission:

```
function check_if_capcha_is_filled (e) {
    if(allowSubmit) return true;
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Fill in the capcha!');
}
```

Finally add in the form the `onsubmit` attribute:

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="check_if_capcha_is_filled">
```

---

**Note:** as mentioned in the comments, a **server validation is still needed**. The code prevents accidentally submitting the form unless the capcha is filled and **is only for user's convenience**.

Comment: What's to stop me from entering a javascript console and just setting `submit = true` myself?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Absolutely nothing. It's (my answer) just for user's convenience. The idea is to prevent them from accidentally submitting the form (e.g. pressing enter on an <input>) without having filled the capcha. Just saving a page reload for better user experience.

Comment: Oh, I got your point now. I should have explicitly mentioned that a server check is still required. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 17):

I found this to be a quick & easy way to do it. Add this to your headers:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var recaptcha = document.forms["myForm"]["g-recaptcha-response"];
  recaptcha.required = true;
  recaptcha.oninvalid = function(e) {
    // do something
    alert("Please complete the captcha");
  }
}
</script>
```

This only works in HTML5, and is (or should be) supported by these browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

(The JS console in Chrome shows this error message: ["Invalid form control" only in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168645/invalid-form-control-only-in-google-chrome) , and I haven't been able to work around this. Hopefully someone else will improve this response.)

Comment: This works when you test manually. But will this work if the form will be submitted by a bot? :D It might not.

Answer (score 12):

I checked for existance of #g-recaptcha-response:

```
function checkRecaptcha() {
    res = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();

    if (res == "" || res == undefined || res.length == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

//...

$('#frm-signup').submit(function(e) {

    if(!checkRecaptcha()) {
        $( "#frm-result" ).text("Please validate your reCAPTCHA.");
        return false;
    }
    //...
});
```

This really should be part of the docs...

Answer (score 5):

**Working solution in 2022**

Personally, I was not able to get any of the above solutions to work with my captcha. So I figured I would share my current working solution for those facing the same issue.

The accepted answer doesn't have a validation technique for when the captcha expires, the below solution addresses that.

My notes in the `.js` should explain the solution thoroughly.

JavaScript

```js
// By default do not allow form submission.
var allow_submit = false

function captcha_filled () {
    /*
     * This is called when Google get's the recaptcha response and approves it.
     * Setting allow_submit = true will let the form POST as normal.
     * */

    allow_submit = true
}

function captcha_expired () {
    /*
     * This is called when Google determines too much time has passed and expires the approval.
     * Setting allow_submit = false will prevent the form from being submitted.
     * */

    allow_submit = false
}


function check_captcha_filled (e) {
    console.log('captcha-verified')
    /*
     * This will be called when the form is submitted.
     * If Google determines the captcha is OK, it will have
     * called captcha_filled which sets allow_submit = true
     * If the captcha has not been filled out, allow_submit
     * will still be false.
     * We check allow_submit and prevent the form from being submitted
     * if the value of allow_submit is false.
     * */

    // If captcha_filled has not been called, allow_submit will be false.
    // In this case, we want to prevent the form from being submitted.
    if (!allow_submit) {
        // This call prevents the form submission.
        // e.preventDefault()

        // This alert is temporary - you should replace it with whatever you want
        // to do if the captcha has not been filled out.
        alert('ERROR: Please verify you are human by filling out the captcha')

        return false
    }
    captcha_expired()
    return true
}
```

HTML

```html
<form action="post" onsubmit="return check_captcha_filled()">
<!-- form items -->
<div class="g-recaptcha"
   data-callback="captcha_filled"
   data-expired-callback="captcha_expired"
   data-sitekey="your site key">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That may be the case, becuase this question was little old, as Captcha library changes we may need to update the jQuery according that.

Comment: @BaikareSandip I'm unsure if I follow. There is no jQuery in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more friendly and descriptive message, you can add a required checkbox.
This will ensure the html5 popup shows something like: **"Please check this box if you want to proceed"**

```
<div class="captcha">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Your Site Key" data-callback="removeFakeCaptcha"></div>
   <input type="checkbox" class="captcha-fake-field" tabindex="-1" required>
</div>
```

Add the code to remove the fake captcha once completed

```
window.removeFakeCaptcha = function() {
   document.querySelector('.captcha-fake-field').remove();
}
```

Then on the css you hide the checkbox and position it to the captcha box:

```
.captcha {
  position: relative;
}
.captcha-fake-field {
  background: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: it's not working properly. Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already solved this, but you could use an addon to validate the Google recaptcha:
http://formvalidation.io/addons/recaptcha2/

Comment: page not found. Please try to put answer instead of links

Answer (score 0):

I find this very helpful:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha myPopover" data-sitekey="Your Key" 
        data-callback="recaptchaCallback">
```

You add a function to data-callback="recaptchaCallback" with this code:

```
var recaptchachecked=false; 
function recaptchaCallback() {
    recaptchachecked = true;
}
```

and a function were you return the value to use it in a other html-tag like this:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return isreCaptchaChecked()">
function isreCaptchaChecked()
{
    return recaptchachecked;
}
```

I hope this helps you.