# Google ReCAPTCHA as a Required field in a form

Tags: php, recaptcha, required

I have a Help Desk PHP and I want ReCAPTCHA field set to required. This is a Row in my `register.php` file:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if (ALLOW_REGISTER <> "yes"){
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-info\" style=\"width: 175px;\">Registration is Closed</div>";
include("includes/footer.php");
exit;
}
?>

<h1><?php echo TITLE; ?> ثبت نام</h1>
<table class="<?php echo $table_style_2;?>" style='width: auto;'>
<form action="register_action.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<tr>
<td>نام:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>نام کاربری:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="login" onblur="showResult(this.value)" required> <span id="txtHint"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ایمیل:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>پسورد:</td>
<td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="at least 5 characters"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Human Verification<br></td>
<td><div name="captcha" id="captcha" required class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfrTQcTAAAAAHEoysvy3bQQaOo1vm7GTbYb4YDg"></div></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

But anyone can register without doing the ReCAPTCHA! Any helps to make the ReCAPTCHA Required?  and BTW before I use recaptcha in my website , I use `simple-php-captcha.php` as captcha and have `captcha for registration` in my `config.php` which is `yes`

---

This is some of my `register_action.php` file:

```
<?php include("includes/session.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ثبت نام</title>
<?php
include("config.php");
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/ez_sql_core.php");
include("includes/ez_sql_mysqli.php");
include("includes/functions.php");
//initilize db
$db = new ezSQL_mysqli(db_user,db_password,db_name,db_host);

if (ALLOW_REGISTER <> "yes"){
echo "<p>Registration is Closed</p>";
include("includes/footer.php");
exit;
}

if (CAPTCHA_REGISTER == "yes"){
$captchasession = $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];
$captcha = $db->escape(trim($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']));
if($captchasession <> $captcha) {
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" style=\"max-width: 350px;\">Invalid Captcha Code.</div>";
include("includes/footer.php");
exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using any php framework? You presented the form itself, but validation of entered data is done in PHP script after submitting, in `register_action.php`. Have you changed it there?

Comment: no I didn't change the `register_action.php` file

Comment: I just posted a solution for this, using JS, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491825/5319318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But anyone can register without doing the ReCAPTCHA! Any helps to make the ReCAPTCHA Required?

reCAPTCHA is verified at server-side, not at client-side. It is not required at POST time, but should be verified after.

Have a look into my project code:

```
public static function verifyCaptcha() {
    global $CFG;

    if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) || !is_string($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
        return false;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=" . urlencode($CFG['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE']) . "&response=" . urlencode($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!json_decode($result)->success)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

For your script:

```
if (CAPTCHA_REGISTER == "yes"){
    $privatekey = "??????";
    $rcres = trim($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=" . urlencode($privatekey) . "&response=" . urlencode($rcres));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!json_decode($result)->success){
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" style=\"max-width: 350px;\">Invalid Captcha Code.</div>";
        include("includes/footer.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Just have to set `$privatekey` now.

Comment: can you help me with this code? i don't know where to use it.

Comment: Please show you file where the data is POSTed to and validated. (Edit your question.)

Comment: @Aria: See the edit of my answer. You should edit the question than posting another answer.....