# chrome form submission error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I keep getting "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable."

I have a form with couple of input control as required. I also have a input control (required) outside of the form but referenced by form='formid' attribute.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input form="form1" name="text1" type="text" required/>
  </div>

<form id='form1'>
  <div>
    <input name="text2" type="text" required/>
    <input name="text3" type="text" required/>
  </div>

  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Problem: when I submit the form I keep getting "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable."

I do not have any invisible textboxes and by default text1 is focused already.

Comment: Remove 'required' from the offending input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168645/invalid-form-control-only-in-google-chrome

Comment: I can't duplicate using your example: http://jsfiddle.net/555j0ssq/